# НЕ записываются все данные в txt(проблема в цикле?) нужно чтобы записались все номера что и в консоли

Tags: python, url, bs4

```
import sys 
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://online-sms.org/ru'

request = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(request.text, 'html.parser')

teme = soup.find_all('div',{'class':'row nbox'})


for temes in teme:
    temes = temes.find('a',{'class':'npn nol'})
    print(temes.text)

    f = open('numbers.txt', 'w')
    f.write(temes.text)
    f.close
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну тогда открывайте на дополнение, а очищайте его каждую итерацию в цикле.

```
open('numbers.txt', 'a')
```

Или откройте файл один раз перед циклом

```
f = open('numbers.txt', 'w')
for ...:
    ...
f.close()
```